# Max quota for all services by default. What drawbacks?

Tags: c#, wcf

I frequently see that people when write code increases their MessageSize and buffer quota to unbelievable sizes. Like **int.MaxValue** or something. Also add behaviors with big MaxItemsInObjectGraph set to **int.MaxValue**.

So what drawbacks awaits for them? What problems it can cause? Why not set this by default in all cases?

Comment: It's not set by default as it would facilitate denial of service attacks.

Comment: So, only reason for this is protection?